# rsweb reportviewer SSRS resizing

Tags: css, reporting-services

I am using rsweb:ReportViewer to display a SSRS report on an aspx page.  All the other images on the page respond to resizing the page down to mobile device size by resizing the images to the appropriate size.  Does anyone know how to make that happen with the rsweb:ReportViewer?

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="AMReportViewer" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowBackButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowPrintButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <ServerReport ReportPath="REPORT" ReportServerUrl="SERVER" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: You could be more specific by showing some code, or screen-shot of what you are getting error in, to make it more understandable and easier to follow.

Comment: I have added my code